# error convert sample rate from AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

convert sample rate from AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16 and play the openAL, get the following error(http://joxi.ru/B_JkUdg5CbDrWhe9oNI)

```
CONV_FUNC (AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, int16_t, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT, av_clip_int16 (lrintf (* (const float *) pi * (1 << 15))))
```

in file audioconvert.c

my code

```
swrContext = swr_alloc();
av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "in_channel_layout",  cc->channel_layout, 0);
av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "out_channel_layout", cc->channel_layout,  0);
av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "in_sample_rate",     cc->sample_rate, 0);
av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "out_sample_rate",    cc->sample_rate, 0);
av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swrContext, "in_sample_fmt",  cc->sample_fmt, 0);
av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swrContext, "out_sample_fmt", AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P,  0);
swr_init(swrContext);

uint8_t *output;
int out_samples = (int)av_rescale_rnd(swr_get_delay(swrContext, 44100) + (int64_t)decoded_frame->nb_samples, 44100, 44100, AV_ROUND_UP);
swr_convert(swrContext, &output, out_samples, (const uint8_t **)decoded_frame->extended_data, decoded_frame->nb_samples); //error
alBufferData(BufID,AL_FORMAT_STEREO16,output, decsize,44100);
```

may have other solutions?

may have other solutions? I'm doing on the [How to convert sample rate from AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989397/how-to-convert-sample-rate-from-av-sample-fmt-fltp-to-av-sample-fmt-s16)

Answer (score 0):

rushed to the issue the problem was output

```
uint8_t * output [x];
```

- Error gone

Comment: How did you fix it? I am trying to convert from S16 to S16P and code crashes on the line `CONV_FUNC(AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, int16_t, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16,  *(const int16_t*)pi)`