# How to convert AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16 to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, sample, pcm

I use ffmpeg to decode audio and use libmp3lame to encode it into mp3. As libmp3lame inside ffmpeg needs S16P instead of S16, I have to convert audio samples.

I tried using swr_convert but everytime I get a random crash. I started to have doubt if swr_convert accepts S16 as input or not.

So, how can I convert audio samples from AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16 to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find anything ?